# Биос не загружает загрузочную флешку после windows 10

Tags: windows, bios

Проблема такова: после установки windows 10 биос отказывается загружать загрузочную флешку. Уже год как пользуюсь windows 7, но помню, что переход с win 10 -> win 7 я совершил через консоль (форматировал хард, а дальше...).

Пробовал гуглить проблему - в биосе выключал\включал `UEFI Boot` - без толку. Когда пытаюсь загрузить флешку, выдает черный экран, а через секунд 10-15 уже вижу окно приветствия win 7. Да, когда загружаю флешку, пропадает логотип с загрузкой win 7. В биосе нету опции `Secure Boot` или подобного.

Пробовал эту же флешку загрузить на другом компьютере - все работает.

Модель ноутбука: Samsung NP350V5C, на флешке Linux Mint

Answer (score -1):

В BIOS в разделе boot необходимо выставить параметр:

"OS Mode Selection" на "UEFI  and Legacy OS"

Comment: Перечитайте, пожалуйста, мой вопрос. Я ясно сказал, что переключение `UEFI Boot` никак не повлияло на загрузку.

Comment: У вас там 3 параметра для выбора или 2?

Comment: Данной опции - `OS Mode Selection` вообще нету в биосе. Есть лишь `UEFI Boot`. Весь биос облазил - ничего, связанное с `Legacy`, `Secure`, `UEFI`, не нашел. Даже `Legacy USB Support` нету. Флешка ни в какую не хочет загружаться. Попробую позже через CD/DVD-RW загрузиться.

Comment: Попробуйте во вкладке Advanced параметр AHCI Mode Control поменяйте на manual или auto точно не помню.

Comment: Нет, все равно загружает windows. Если поставить на `manual`, то загрузка windows завершается bsod-ом.